# XPath: How to search with AB--AB for AB??AB or AB?-AB

Tags: xpath, match

If you have a String, lets assume: `AB--AB`. I want to look for nodes with xpath which can be `AB??AB`, meaning that the question marks in the node attribute are some kind of a placeholder - and they can vary in their amount of occurrence, so it should also be matched to `AB?-AB` for example.
How can you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath 2.0 has regular expression support: `matches($string, 'AB.{0,2}AB')` would match if the string is a sequence of the literal `AB` followed by zero, one or two arbitrary characters followed by the literal `AB`.

Answer (score 2):

With XPath 1.0, you have to stick with `substring(....)`, `substring-before(....)`, `substring-after(....)`, `starts-with(...)` and `string-length(...)`. Sadly there even isn't an `ends-with(...)` function.

A possible solution to allow all strings starting and ending with "AB" and at least characters in between might be (I'm not totally sure on your needs):

```
//foo[
    starts-with(., 'AB')
  and
    substring(., string-length(.)-1, 2) = 'AB'
  and
    string-length(.) >= 6
  ]
```

Comment: I like the way you wrote the xpath expression..:) The syntax style.So *+1*